# C# LINQ to create a temporary variable with dynamic index

Tags: c#, linq

```
var newList = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Symbol })
            .Select
            (
                x =>
                {
                    var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();

                    return subList.Select((y, idx) => new
                    {
                        Symbol = y.Symbol,
                        Close = y.Close,
                        Date = y.Date,
                        /*p = (idx < 1) ? null : subList.Skip(idx - 1)
                          .Take(2).Select(o => o.Close).ToList()*/,
                        Vol = (idx < 1) ? 0 : new DescriptiveStatistics
                           (subList.Skip(idx - 1).Take(2).Select(o => (double)o.Close/(double)
                           subList.ElementAt(idx - 1).Close).ToList()).StandardDeviation,

                    });
                }
            )
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToList();
```

I want create a variable `p = (idx < 1) ? null : subList.Skip(idx - 1).Take(2).Select(o => o.Close).ToList()` with the same index `idx` of `Vol` but do not appear in the `return` just a temporary variable(but have to use the synchronous `idx` as `Vol`). So where to write down this `p` or how to change the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold a temp variable, just like you have done with `subList` although I dont have a test structure to build against something like this below should work.

```
var newList = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Symbol })
.Select
(
    x =>
    {
        var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();
        return subList.Select((y, idx) => { //return is a function not an object
            var p = (idx < 1) ? null : subList.Skip(idx - 1).Take(2).Select(o => o.Close).ToList(); //your p

            return new //this return returns the object definition
            {
                Symbol = y.Symbol,
                Close = y.Close,
                Date = y.Date,
                Vol = p == null ? 0 : new DescriptiveStatistics(subList.Skip(idx - 1).Take(2).Select(o => (double)o.Close / (double)subList.ElementAt(idx - 1).Close).ToList()).StandardDeviation,
            };
        });
    }
)
.SelectMany(x => x)
.ToList();
```

Comment: So, this can guarantee `p` and `Vol` share the same `idx` ?  Why can't we  ormit the first `return` in `return subList.Select((y, idx) => {`?

Comment: The first return statement is returning a query against your `subList` variable where your `p` variable is based on the `idx` of each item in your `subList` not data.

Comment: And how could I search the related information about such double parameters `(y, idx)` for the functions in linq, since it is not correct when I use `orderby(y, idx) =>.` I really want to know related knowledge.

Comment: `Orderby` doesnt have an index parameter. It is  simply a key selector expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx